# How do I put multiple values in one column, and should I?

Tags: database

I am making a Forum for which I am planning to make a points system. You can like and dislike to make it go up or down.

The problem I am having is that I need to know who voted, and I thought that i should put the ID's of all users who have voted in another column. But I don't know how to efficiently do it, or if I should do it that way.

The only thing I could come up with is adding values in this order: '1, 2, 5, 6, 8'. This way I can get the records with php, add or remove an ID, and insert it again.

I do feel that there is a better way to do such a thing, and would like to have some input for that.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have an `articles` table in your forum and a `users` table, both with a column `id` I'd recommend a third table `articles_votes` with columns `users_id` and `article_id` containing the `users.id` and `articles.id` users voted for.

```
select count(*) from articles_votes
where articles_votes.article_id = 5
```

should give you the amount of votes for article number 5.